# Are CRLs checked by Azure IoT Edge?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

In this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist#networking, many URLs are mentioned, but nothing about CRLs for certificates used with IoT Hub, DPS or Blob Storage.  Does IoT Edge verify CRLs and if using PrivateEndpoints or PrivateLink, do I need to be concerned about CRL checking?

Comment: You will need to make sure you can connect to your root certificate authority (CA) like Baltimore, Verisign, DigiCert, or GlobalSign if you have purchased your certificate from a trusted commercial certificate authority. A CRL is issued by a CRL issuer, which is typically the CA which also issued the corresponding certificates. I will nevertheless check if Azure IoT Edge uses other trusted authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks AS Azevedo for the answer and the later conversation.  For others, IoT Edge does not check the CRL, meaning when using a Private Endpoint, Edge will not attempt and fail to talk to a CRL.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding some extra info: IoT Edge certificates strategy centers around issuance of short-lived and fast retiring certificates to obviate the need for CRLs. @Kevin Saye feel free to add that info to your own answer. Thanks